# using Multiple using statements to dispose DataSet and DataTables

Tags: c#, dataset, disposing

Can you please explain what is happening here?

```
using(DataSet ds = GetDataSet()) // will this get disposed? if yes (when?)
{
    using(DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]) /* in this line is ds available for dt? i found some issue with this kind of statement. dt gets null after this line */
    {
          // i know that ds is available here.
          //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: ds should be available for all lines of code up to the closing brace of the using if i'm not mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using(DataSet ds = GetDataSet()){

  using(DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0])
  // dt will be NULL if there are no tables in ds
  {
    // both dt & ds will be available here

  }// dt will get disposed

}// ds will be disposed at this point...
```

The equivalent code for this is:

```
try{
 DataSet ds = GetDataSet();
 try{
  DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
  // dt will not be null if there are any tables in ds
  // Both ds & dt available here...
 }
 finally{
  dt.Dispose();
 }
}
finally{
 ds.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ds` will be disposed, at the last end bracket in your sample.  Yes, `ds` is available when you're constructing `dt`.  The reason `dt` is coming through as `null` must simply be that `ds.Tables[0]` is returning null.  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfsd7dz4.aspx), the `null` value means that the `DataTable` you're looking for doesn't exist.  My guess is that the `DataSet` isn't being filled with values.  See the documentation for [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The `using()` statement takes any `IDisposable` and will call `Dispose()` on it when it's scope is exited either via exception or normal execution.

Thus `dt` will be disposed first when it passes the inner closing `}`, and then `ds` will be disposed when the outer closing '}` is passed:

```
using(DataSet ds = GetDataSet()) 
{
    using(DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]) 
    {
        ....
    } // <-- dt disposed here or if unhandled exception thrown

} // <-- ds disposed here or if unhandled exception thrown.
```

For more information, see the [MSDN section on the Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be disposed after you leave the from the corresponding bracket. Using calls dispose and it can only be used with objects that implement IDisposable.

Comment: There is no closure in the posted code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

Comment: Aye, my bad, I used "closure" word to describe {}

Answer (score 0):

The [using statment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) here:

```
using (ResourceType resource = expression) { ... }
```

is equivalent to:

```
ResourceType resource = expression;
try {
    ...
}
finally {
   if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
}
```

(if `ResourceType` is a value type, the null check will be omitted).

So in your case, the first using makes sense assuming `GetDataSet()` creates a new dataset that nobody else will be using later. The second `using` doesn't make much sense - you don't need to dispose of dataset tables, as far as I know.

The reason you're getting a null `dt` may be that there is nothing in the `Tables` collection.

Answer (score 0):

think like this:

`using resource`

your `resource` will live here and will be available to all other children "using" statements or other methods

`end of using`

so to your questions:

`ds` will get disposed in the end of the first `using` block

`dt` will get the first `DataTable` found in `ds` and will be disposed in the end of its own `using` block

This happens because the `using` statement, in this form will always call the `Dispose` method of the resource it's managing, therefore, you can only use the `using` block for types that implement `IDisposable`